# Two BackgroudService called periodically in ASP.Net Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, scheduled-tasks, background-service, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on a web application in ASP.Net Core5. In this application, I created two background processes.
I need to run them periodically. Like,

```
Task 01 runs first, 
after 10 seconds task 02 runs, 
then after 10 seconds task 01 runs, 
then after 10 seconds task 02 runs,
and so on.
```

I have done this so far:

```
public class RunTaskPeriodically : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    public RunTaskPeriodically(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using(var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                Log.Information($"Task Running");

                var myService1 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITaskOne>();
                var myService2 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITaskTwo>();

                await myService1.DoTask(stoppingToken);
                await myService2.DoTask(stoppingToken);
            }
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I execute them periodically as requirements?

Comment: I would look into using something like https://www.hangfire.io/
its a great tool for executing scheduled tasks at different times without having to create another background task service.

Comment: @traveler3468, thank you so much. I used hangfire for one task, but my team lead asked me not to use any third party packages.

Comment: removing `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), stoppingToken);` and then adding `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), stoppingToken);` between `await myService1.DoTask(stoppingToken); await myService2.DoTask(stoppingToken);` should be ok then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the injection of `IServiceScopeFactory` as it will trap you in the **service provider anti pattern**, or so they say.  I guess it is OK to have the service provider pattern for the IoC container only.  Anyway, I digress.

```cs
public class RunTaskPeriodically : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    private readonly Func<IServiceScope, Func<CancellationToken, Task>>[] _tasksToRun;
    public RunTaskPeriodically(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        _tasksToRun = new[]
        {
            scope =>
            {
                var svc = scope.GetRequiredService<ITaskOne>();
                return (ct => svc.DoTask(ct));
            },
            scope =>
            {
                var svc = scope.GetRequiredService<ITaskTwo>();
                return (ct => svc.DoTask(ct));
            }
        };
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        ulong id = 0L;
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using(var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                Log.Information($"Task Running");
                await _tasksToRun[id++](scope)(stoppingToken);
            }
            id = id % 2;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

On construction of the background service, you create an array of functions that receive a scope and return a function that receives a cancellation token and returns a task.

Then, on the `while` loop, you use simple arithmetics to calculate the task that is meant to be executed next.

---

This is done assuming you really need a new scope every time you'll be requesting for the service task.  Consider having just one scope and simply instantiating the service classes under the same scope.